# Can't install setuptools on Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit

Tags: python, windows-7, setuptools

I'm trying to install setuptools on Windows 7 Premium 32 bit. I've downloaded the installer `setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe` from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files and when I try to install it, I'm getting the following error: `Python 2.7 is required, which was not found in the registry`. Well, I know for a fact that Python 2.7.2 is installed right now. I've looked online and the only thing I see is troubles installing on Windows 7 64 bit. Has anyone else run in to this issue or know how to resolve?

**Edit**

Adding for visibility.

I searched the registry and I didn't find the install path anywhere. I added it back HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\ and it didn't fix the install error.

**Edit 2**

I found a solution. I downloaded and ran: http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py

Comment: Could you type python in start menu and see which idle version starts up ? Also type cmd and in the command prompt type python... Does python 2.7 prompt come ?

Comment: Yes. It does. Now, I searched the registry and I didn't find the install path anywhere. I added it back HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\

Comment: It doesn't. Has the same error.

Comment: Does repairing your python installation help ? Try to run the installation exe again with only repair as the option...

Comment: Unfortunately not. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to install it. I downloaded http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py and ran it. Installed without issue.

Comment: To 'run it' in python: `>>> ez_setup.download_setuptools()`

Answer (score 0):

Check that you've one of your `PATH environmental variable` set to the location where python is installed.

[Check this link for more info](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#configuring-python)

Comment: I just double check and the install path is listed in the PATH variable.